# Conditions for Fubini's theorem

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

To preface this post, I have to admit that I have extremely little measure theory knowledge and I get lost when trying to read about Fubini's theorem for this reason. In the theorem statement for [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), it says that

$$\int_{A\times B}|f(x,y)|d(x,y) < \infty.$$

I get that it is saying that $|f|$ - when integrated over the product measure - is finite but how does one go about checking that this is the case? Is it sufficient to show the following:

$$\int_{A}\left(\int_{B}|f(x,y)|dy\right)dx < \infty$$

I found a [resource](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~rich/Fubini.pdf) (PDF warning) that talks about a corollary to Fubini's theorem that seems to suggest that this condition is sufficient (see Corollary 6.2.1 and the remark following it) however they restrict themselves to $\sigma$-finite measure spaces but the theorem statement on Wikipedia allows for general complete measure spaces. Is my assertion correct or am I way off the mark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has actually an [alternate theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Alternate_theorem_statement) statement that answers the question. Besides $\sigma$-finiteness, *both* iterated integrals of the absolute value of the function have to be finite.

Now $\sigma$-finiteness is implicitely required in Fubini's theorem to some degree. The assumption $$\int_{A\times B}|f(x,y)|d(x,y) < \infty.$$ implies that $F_n=\{(x,y):|f(x,y)|>1/n\}$ has finite measure, so the product measure restricted to $\bigcup_n F_n=\{(x,y):f(x,y)\neq 0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: With your last statement, colloquially does it mean that the area of the set over which $f$ is nonzero is finite?

Comment: @CameronWilliams It can be infinite, but it is always $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: I see. Well I guess I have reading to do. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: After reading the $\sigma$-finite Wiki article I think I realized I mistook $\sigma$-finiteness to mean finite measure. What a silly mistake. Thanks for clearing it up for me.